# is anything wrong with this php-sql query?

Tags: php, sql

Could you check what's wrong with this sql query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   A.a
A.b
FROM tableAA AS A
INNER JOIN(tableBB AS B)
ON(A.a= B.a)
INNER JOIN(tableCC AS C)
ON(A.a = C.a)
INNER JOIN(tableDD AS D)
ON(A.a = D.a)

WHERE 

  B.c = '$selectedtype' AND
  B.d NOT LIKE '%$selection%' AND
  C.e='$selction111' 
OR
    D.c = '$selectedtype' AND
A.d NOT LIKE '%$selection%' AND
    C.e='$selction111'
```

I have concerns about OR conditions, what i want here that either the conditions between 'where' and 'OR' are true or below the 'OR' are true.

Is the way of writing correct? or is there any other way to write?

Comment: My rule of thumb is that anytime you have a combination of AND and OR in a WHERE condition, you should use parenthesized grouping to make it clear what the intended order of operations is.

Comment: `AND` > `OR`, but parenthesis help you to do less thinking.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for:

```
(B.c = '$selectedtype' AND B.d NOT LIKE '%$selection%' AND C.e='$selction111')
OR
(D.c = '$selectedtype' AND A.d NOT LIKE '%$selection%' AND C.e='$selction111')
```